# Sharepoint Email workflow not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My SharePoint designer 2013 email workflow isn't sending emails to Outlook 2010 users.  The emails are being sent to Outlook 2013, 2016 and Office 365 users. How do I fix this issue for Outlook 2010 users?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out some of these posts if you haven't already. It seems like they had some similar issues.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2afcf6fd-8aa3-4893-a238-f752d1cbf92a/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-not-sending-email?forum=sharepointdevelopment

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0d83bea4-62bb-40eb-8bf1-a5f2044b8ae7/send-an-email-workflow-action-not-working-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3c76459c-01f5-4d75-be17-ee5b2ce1c1dd/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-not-sending-emails?forum=sharepointgeneral